# work with the zoom in the figure

Tags: matlab, zooming

I run the following code in matlab

```
figure
t = 0:pi/50:10*pi;
subplot(1,2,1); plot3(sin(t),cos(t),t);
title('Normal');
subplot(1,2,2); plot3(sin(t),cos(t),t); 
axis equal;
title('Axis equal')
```

and i obtain this [image]

but when I zoom in the left figure, this figure is obtained[image], ie occupies the entire image. What is the problem ?

Comment: This seems like a rendering bug [best provided to The MathWorks](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/).

Comment: Actually I don't think it's a bug, seems like the right axes' background obscures the large helix... That's all... Try making it invisible and see what happens :)

Comment: @Dev-iL it is a bug, repeatable in R2015b as well. The zoom behavior of `plot3` subplots does not match that of `plot` subplots.

Comment: I didn't do my due diligence googling yesterday, apparently this has been an issue [since at least 2009](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/259319). The response from The MathWorks was: `The ability to zoom on a 3D figure without causing it to expand is not currently available in MATLAB.
Our developers are aware of the difference between the two functionalities and they are considering improving it for a future release.`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [official article on zoom](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/enlarging-the-view.html).

> 3-D zooming does not change the axes limits, as in 2-D zooming. Instead it changes the view (specifically, the axes CameraViewAngle property) as if you were looking through a camera with a zoom lens.

So I think that the behavior you describe is no surprise. To achieve similar 2D zoom, I think it's possible to use `axis` to change the limit. Maybe something like this

```
figure
t = 0:pi/50:10*pi;
subplot(1,2,1); plot3(sin(t),cos(t),t);
ax1=gca;
title('Normal');
subplot(1,2,2); plot3(sin(t),cos(t),t); 
axis equal;
title('Axis equal')

% zoom by factor k
fzoom = @(x,k) ([-(x(2)-x(1))/k,(x(2)-x(1))/k] + (x(2)+x(1))) /2;

% get current axis limits
lims = axis(ax1);
x = lims(1:2);
y = lims(3:4);
z = lims(5:6);

% Zoom in every dimensions 120%
axis(ax1,[fzoom(x,1.2),fzoom(y,1.2),fzoom(z,1.2)]);
```

Comment: Mine seems to work fine at 1.2 zoom factor, [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/stTcG.png). I use r2013a. Anyway, i found a way to kinda zoom in interactively. First, use the **Rotate 3d** button, right click the axes, Go to **X-Y Views**. Next, you can use **Zoom** button to zoom in/out like in 2D as you wish. After that, you can **rotate 3d** to view around the plot.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to link the cameraposition of the both subplot with:

```
figure
t = 0:pi/50:10*pi;
s(1) = subplot(1,2,1); plot3(sin(t),cos(t),t);
title('Normal');
s(2) = subplot(1,2,2); plot3(sin(t),cos(t),t); 
axis equal;
title('Axis equal')

linkprop(s, 'CameraPosition'); %link the cameraposition
```

you can also try to change the renderer mode:

```
set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'painters'); %3 choices: 'painters','opengl','zbuffer'
```

Comment: Neither one of these changes the behavior. Plus, linking `CameraPosition` destroys the `axis` differences. Please test things before you submit them.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try to change the figure renderer. It once helped me to solve similar problem.
2. If still not working. You can work around by listen to zoom by addlistener command to xlim or ylim property. And as callback set the axes outerposition to the proper value.

Comment: This is not an answer. Changing the figure renderer does not fix the issue. Setting `XLim` and `YLim` also will not fix the issue because the entire axes object is being modified, not the data in view.

Comment: @excaza xlim is just to catch the zoom event and not to set. Once you catch the event, you can handle the position property and fix the bad new position that you get after the zoom.

Comment: You're missing my point. The data is not zoomed at all in the `plot3` subplot, the entire axes object is. Adjusting the `Position` property will only fix the size of the axes object, not zoom in on the data.

Comment: I see we are not on the same page.
1. "but when I zoom in the left figure" - this bad thing happens to you when you zoom. the bad think is that the axes 'position' property is changing.
2. Lets react to each zoom and then try to fix the position to the original one (assuming you somehow know it or saved it after the plots).
3.

Comment: Continue ...
3. how can we do something after a zoom? In zoom - the xlim and/or the ylim axes prop is changing - so if we will listen to these properties we can do something (callback) after the zoom (postSet) -> setting back the axes position (not reflect the data nor the zoom) back to the original position you wanted.

Comment: I'm not going to continue discussing this with you until you actually attempt to use your solution. The axes limits are not changing, which you would see if you actually ran the code.